# como parar un while?

Tags: ios, swift

Como puedo parar el while cuando mi app esta en foreground? no se como puedo conseguir que mi app se mantenga viva en segundo plano lo consegui con el while pero al traer la app en primer plano se queda como si fuese en segundo plano no vuelve, quiero parar el while cuando la app vuelve en primer plano.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        var finished = false
        var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0);
        bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName:"MyBackgroundTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
            // Time is up.
            if bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid {
                // Do something to stop our background task or the app will be killed
                finished = true
            }
        })
        // Perform your background task here
            print("The task has started")


            while !finished {
                if( finished == false ){
                   print( "no finished")
                }else {
                    finished = true
                    print( "finished")
                }
            }


        // Indicate that it is complete
        application.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
        }
```

e puesto en appWill.... finished = true pero nada

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        finished = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El appDelegate tiene una serie de funciones principales que se deberían usar para pausar una aplicación que va a entrar en background. La idea debería ser guardar el estado de la aplicación para poder recuperarlo al volver a activarse. Intentar mantenerla en activo en background en una mala práctica, e iOS no te permitirá que se sigan ejecutando funciones en background durante mas de unos segundos.

Deberías replantearte el proceso de pausa de aplicación usando los siguientes métodos para guardar el estado de la en el momento de entrar en background y volver a cargarlo cuando se vuelva a activar.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override para personalizar la aplicación después de iniciarla, siempre debe devolver true.
return true
        }

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
// Esta función se ejecuta cuando la aplicación está a punto de pasar del estado activo al inactivo(brackground). Puede ocurrir para ciertos tipos de interrupciones temporales (como una llamada telefónica entrante o un mensaje SMS) o cuando el usuario cierra la aplicación y comienza la transición de la app a estado background.
// Use este método para pausar tareas en curso, deshabilitar temporizadores. Los juegos pueden usar este método para pausar una partida.
        }

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
// La aplicación ha entrado en estado inactivo (brackground) Use este método para liberar recursos, guardar datos de usuario, invalidar temporizadores y almacenar suficiente información del estado de la aplicación para restaurar su aplicación de nuevo en caso de que se cierre luego.
// Si su aplicación admite la ejecución en segundo plano, se llama a este método en lugar de applicationWillTerminate: cuando el usuario cierra la aplicación.
        }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
// Se ejecuta cuando una aplicación va a volver al estado activo aquí puede deshacer muchos de los cambios realizados al ingresar al fondo.
        }

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
// Reinicie las tareas que se detuvieron (o que aún no se iniciaron) mientras la aplicación estaba inactiva. Si la aplicación estaba previamente en segundo plano, opcionalmente puede actualizar la interfaz de usuario.     
        }

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
// Se llama cuando la aplicación está a punto de finalizar. Guarde los datos si corresponde. Ver también applicationDidEnterBackground
// Guarda los cambios en el managed object context de la aplicación antes de que la aplicación finalice.
self.saveContext()
        }
```

Por otra parte desde iOS 13 ha aparecido el soporte de múltiples ventanas de una misma aplicación para iPadOS. Si creas un nuevo proyecto Xcode verás AppDelegate se ha dividido en dos: AppDelegate.swift y SceneDelegate.swift.

El appDelegate debe encargarse de:

- Configurar los datos que necesites durante la aplicación.
- Responder a a cualquier evento que se centre en la aplicación, como
  un archivo que se comparta con usted.
- Regístrese para servicios externos, como notificaciones push.
- Configura tus escenas iniciales.

Por otro lado el SceneDelegate está para gestionar instancias de la interfaz de usuario de su aplicación. Entonces, si el usuario ha creado 2 ventanas que muestran su aplicación, tiene 2 escenas, ambas respaldadas por el mismo AppDelegate.

Estas 2 escenas están diseñadas para funcionar independientemente unas de otras. Por lo que una escena puede entrar en background mientras la otra puede seguir activa. Y el appDelegate ya no se encarga de gestionar ese proceso.

Comment: se que en appdelegate tengo que hacer algo pero no se por donde empezar, con que codigo o como replantear el background mode, tuve el mismo problema con android pero al final consegui crear un servicio al iniciar al app con la notificacion y asi consegui que android no mate mi app en segundo plano pero en ios no se que hacer..... por donde empezar